# How do I show the uniform continuity of $\tan^{-1}$ over $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: uniform-continuity

How do I show the uniform continuity of $\tan^{-1}$ over $\mathbb{R}$ ? I am trying to use the $\epsilon - \delta$ definition. I have just started learning this topic.

Comment: The derivative is bounded by $1$ hence $\delta=\varepsilon$ works, that is: $$\forall\varepsilon\gt0,\ \forall (x,y),\ |x-y|\leqslant\varepsilon\implies|f(x)-f(y)|\leqslant\varepsilon.$$

Comment: "derivative is bounded by 1..." the basic book i am refering to uses only the epsilon-delta definition. I do not know the use of deriatives to prove/disprove uniform continuity. can you please suggest some link where i can read about it ?

Comment: @AmanMittal: I gave you the technique that uses the derivative.

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal can you pleas share some link where i can read more about it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [related problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/322890/uniform-continuity-of-fx-x3). 
**Hint:** You can use the mean value theorem.

**Added:**

$$ \Bigg|\frac{\arctan(x+h)-\arctan(x)}{(x+h)-x}\Bigg| = |\arctan(\zeta)'| \leq 1. $$

$$ \implies \Big|{\arctan(x+h)-\arctan(x)}\Big| \leq |h|< \epsilon=\delta.$$

Comment: i haven't reached that part yet. Do you think i should finish MVT and then come back to this problem ?

Comment: @AmanMittal: This is one approach to the problem which uses the boundedness of the derivative.

Comment: ok, from Lipschitz theorem, a function is uniformly continuous if its derivative is bounded. which holds good here. so where did we apply MVT in this ?

Comment: That cleared it for me. Your another post here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/322890/uniform-continuity-of-fx-x3 was very helpful too. Thanks a lot !!

Comment: @AmanMittal: You are very welcome.

Comment: One side question. If we have $y=\tan x$ then we cannot use this method. can you give some pointer for this problem ?

Comment: $y=\tan x$ isn't uniformly continuous, @AmanMittal

Comment: yes, but how do i go on proving that ?

Comment: It is unbounded on $(0,\pi/2)$. Any uniformly continuous function is necessarily bounded on any bounded interval. @AmanMittal

Comment: I see. Thanks !

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: Thanks for answering the OP.

Answer (score 2):

Here $f : x \mapsto\mathbb \tan^{-1}(x)$ is continuous function and $\displaystyle\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} f(x)$ and $\displaystyle\lim_{x\rightarrow -\infty} f(x)$ exists then $f$ is uniformly continuous.(you can prove this for any continuous function)

Comment: which theorem is that ?

Comment: @AmanMittal this is not a theorem you will have to prove this.

Comment: @AmanMittal just look at this prove http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/346292/uniform-continuity-on-0-infty?rq=1 and try to modify it.

Answer (score 2):

Yet another idea. Use
$$\arctan(x) - \arctan(y) = \arctan\left(\frac{x - y}{1 + xy} \right)$$
and the uniform continuity of $\arctan$ in the compact interval $[-h,h]$, $h>0$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\tan^{-1}(x)=\frac1{1+x^2}\le1
$$

Comment: Hints were permitted in 2013, if that’s what the downvote is about. Otherwise, I don’t see what’s wrong. I would appreciate a comment.