# Is $f(x)=x+\frac{x}{x+1}$ uniformly continuous on $(0,\infty)$

Tags: calculus, continuity

> Is $f(x)=x+\frac{x}{x+1}$ uniformly continuous on $(0,\infty)$

Going from the epsilon delta definition we get:

$$\forall x,y>1,\text{WLOG}:x>y \ ,\ \forall\epsilon>0,\exists\delta>0 \ s.t. \ |x-y|<\delta\rightarrow |x+\frac{x}{x+1}-y-\frac{y}{y+1}|<\epsilon$$

But I'm not really sure on how to continue from here.

Alternatively: if $\lim\limits_{x\to \infty}f(x)$ exists on $[0,\infty)$ then the function is uniformly continuous, well, it's easy to see here that $\lim\limits_{x\to \infty}f(x)=\infty$ but is that enough ?

Comment: $f(x)=x+1-\dfrac1{x+1}$

Comment: Well, is it enough that $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\infty$? You should be able to answer that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer here if you want it, I hope that the spoiler tags work. (If not, could someone tell me how to spoiler multiple lines?)

> Let $a \in (0,\infty)$ be given. 
> Let $\epsilon >0$ be given. 
> Select $\delta=\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ 
> Then, for all $x \in (0,\infty)$ with $|x-a|<\delta$:
> $$|f(x) - f(a)|=\left|x+\frac{x}{x+1} - a -\frac{a}{a+1}\right| \leq |x-a| + \left|\frac{x-a}{(x+1)(a+1)}\right|$$
> $$=|x-a|+\frac{|x-a|}{|x+1||a+1|}\leq |x-a| + |x-a| = 2|x-a| < 2\delta \leq 2\cdot \frac{\epsilon}{2}=\epsilon$$
> Hence, $f$ is continuous at $a$. Since $a \in (0,\infty)$ and $\epsilon >0$ are given arbitrarily, we have: for all $ a \in (0,\infty)$ and all $ \epsilon > 0$, there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that for all $x \in (0,\infty)$ with $|x-a|<\delta$, $|f(x) - f(a)|<\epsilon$. Conclusion: $f$ is continuous.

Comment: To do multiple line spoiler tags, put `>!` like you did, but remove all those extra line breaks. Where you want line breaks, use `<br><br>`

Comment: It seems like naturally there should be 7 line breaks.

Answer (score 2):

Take a smaller bite.  Note that a sum of uniformly continuous functions is uniformly continuous.  We know $x\mapsto x$ is uniformly continuous, so we just deal with $x/(x+1)$.
Also, notice that 
$${x\over x + 1 } = 1 - {1\over x + 1}.$$
Now the job is to show that $x\mapsto 1/(x + 1)$ is uniformly continuous.  Can you do the rest?

Comment: So you're saying that I do have to find an epsilon, but modifying the function should help.

Comment: With this function, it is easy to do the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ tango.

Comment: @GinKin, that limit criterion might come in handy for some of the summands.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Use the mean value theorem. Note that, the derivative of the function is bounded on $(0,\infty)$. See a [related problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/498542/how-do-i-show-the-uniform-continuity-of-tan-1-over-mathbbr).

Comment: Thanks. In one of the answers there they use zeta which I have no idea what it is so we haven't covered that.

Comment: I think using the mean value theorem is the easiest to prove U.continuity since $|f'(x)| \leq 2 $ on $(0,infty)$.

Comment: @Downvoter: What's the downvote for?

Comment: 3 out of 4 answers here got downvoted.

Comment: @GinKin: Do not worry about the down vote.