# Question about natural log function

Tags: real-analysis

Does anyone know how to prove that $\ln(x)$ is uniformly continuous on $[1,\infty)$ by just using the definition of a uniformly continuous function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**: Show that $|\ln(x)-\ln(y)|\le |x-y|$ for all $x\ge1$ and $y\ge 1$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Use the mean value theorem. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/498542/how-do-i-show-the-uniform-continuity-of-tan-1-over-mathbbr).